# How to merge rows to one row in R based on a value in a Column

Tags: r

Firstoff I tried looking for a solution for this on stackoverflow. I might have missed it but I couldn't find or work out a code to do the following:

I want to merge the rows without NA's to one row based on column X1.

```
X1  Sex Age Language

1487252709  NA  22  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  male    NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  Nederlands
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252715  NA  32  NA
1487252715  NA  NA  NA
1487252715  NA  NA  NA
1487252715  male    NA  NA
1487252715  NA  NA  Nederlands
```

My final result should show like this:

```
1487252709  male 22 Nederlands
1487252715  male 32 Nederlands
```

It should be simple right? I think I'm overthinking or something but I just can't figure it out. I tried different functions like rbind and merge but it didn't gave the result that I wanted.

ps: this is my first post, so I hope it's informative enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise_each` with `na.omit` after grouping by 'X1'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(X1) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(na.omit))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
#          X1   Sex   Age   Language
#       <int> <chr> <int>      <chr>
#1 1487252709  male    22 Nederlands
#2 1487252715  male    32 Nederlands
```

As @Uwe mentioned, the `summarise_each` would be deprecated, so in place use `summarise_all`

Comment: As of version 0.7.0 of `dplyr` (on CRAN 2017-06-09), `summarise_each()` has been "soft deprecated" in favour of `summarise_all()` and other functions. For more details, please, see the [`dplyr` Change Log on tidyverse.org](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#deprecated-and-defunct).

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness (and because this question has become a dupe target), here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = X1]
```

> ```
>            X1  Sex Age   Language
> 1: 1487252709 male  22 Nederlands
> 2: 1487252715 male  32 Nederlands
> ```

This solution returns the expected answer for the sample dataset provided by the OP.

#### Edit: More realistic, "untidy" dataset

However, it will fail in case of a more realistic dataset which may contain duplicated rows or where only `NA` values are provided, e.g.,

```
setDT(df2)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = X1]
```

> ```
>            X1  Sex Age   Language
> 1: 1487252709 male  22 Nederlands
> 2: 1487252715 male  32 Nederlands
> 3: 1487252715 male  32 Nederlands
> 4: 1111111111 male  NA         NA
> 5: 1111111111 male  NA         NA
> ```
>
> Warning message: In `[.data.table`(setDT(df2), , lapply(.SD, na.omit),
>   by = X1) :   Item 2 of j's result for group 3 is zero length. This
>   will be filled with 2 NAs to match the longest column in this result.
>   Later groups may have a similar problem but only the first is reported
>   to save filling the warning buffer.

---

Note that the `dplyr` solution will throw an error in this case:

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(X1) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(na.omit))
```

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `Sex` must be length
>   1 (a summary value), not 2

---

To cover these edge cases as well, the aggregation function needs to be modified:

```
df2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) first(na.omit(x))), by = X1]
```

> ```
>            X1  Sex Age   Language
> 1: 1487252709 male  22 Nederlands
> 2: 1487252715 male  32 Nederlands
> 3: 1111111111 male  NA         NA
> 4: 9999999999   NA  NA         NA
> ```

#### Data

Dataset as provided by the OP:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread(
  "X1  Sex Age Language
1487252709  NA  22  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  male    NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  Nederlands
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252709  NA  NA  NA
1487252715  NA  32  NA
1487252715  NA  NA  NA
1487252715  NA  NA  NA
1487252715  male    NA  NA
1487252715  NA  NA  Nederlands"
)
```

More realistic, "untidy" dataset:

```
df2 <- fread(
  "X1  Sex Age Language
  1487252709  NA  22  NA
  1487252709  NA  NA  NA
  1487252709  male    NA  NA
  1487252709  NA  NA  Nederlands
  1487252709  NA  NA  NA
  1487252709  NA  NA  NA
  1487252715  NA  32  NA
  1487252715  NA  NA  NA
  1487252715  NA  NA  NA
  1487252715  male    NA  NA
  1487252715  NA  NA  Nederlands
  1487252715  NA  NA  Nederlands
  1111111111  male    NA  NA
  1111111111  male    NA  NA
  9999999999  NA  NA  NA"
)
```